# Moving object from Position_1 to Position_2 during [Timestamp_1, Timestamp_2]

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I am building a webpage game and wanna start moving an object at Timestamp_1 from Position_1 towards Position_2. The object should arrive at Position_2 at Timestamp_2. Since I know the coordinates of both Position_1 and Position_2, I can calculate the speed. What is the proper technique to implement this? I am trying HTML Canvas with Javascript's `setInterval` but am wondering if there is any framework or tool that fulfill this requirement. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setInterval` it's better to use the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

For start I highly recommend to take a look at [Foundation HTML5 Animation with JavaScript](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/)

Of course there are frameworks to do 2d and 3d games/animations such as [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com), [CreateJS](https://createjs.com), [Three.js](https://threejs.org) (off the top of my head). But again I would recommend to become familiar with basics first.

Good luck!